# Extracting specific information from Terraform apply output in a DevOps pipeline

Tags: python, automation, terraform, cloud, devops

I'm working in a software company where we have a DevOps cycle with a pipeline that includes GCP, Git, Jenkins, and Terraform for building, testing, and deploying websites in the cloud. We use Terraform's configuration and variable files to manage client-specific details, with the variable file maintained by our Infrastructure Team and executed by the Operation Team.

The challenge we're facing is that when we initiate a Terraform plan via Git, the Terraform apply output generates thousands of lines of information, making it difficult for us to extract only the relevant details. We're specifically interested in identifying the lines that have changed in the Terraform variable file, determining the success of the pipeline, and pinpointing any errors caused by the actions of the Operation Team.

I'm seeking advice and suggestions on how to address this issue and extract the necessary information from the Terraform apply output more effectively. Are there any best practices or techniques to filter and analyze the output to obtain the desired insights?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Is it possibly to pass a python code in terraform configuration file or any other way?

Comment: If you want to customize the presentation of the information from Terraform, I'd suggest starting by using the `-json` option when you run `terraform apply` to get a JSON serialization of the underlying events that normally drive the UI, and then you can parse that output and use it to produce whatever alternative presentation you want. It should be possible to consume that JSON output in any language that can read lines from a pipe and parse them as JSON.

Comment: In our CI/CD pipeline, we already have a step for Terraform apply to apply infrastructure changes. However, I am interested in capturing information specifically after the Terraform apply steps, such as the changed lines in the Terraform variable file, the success status of the pipeline, and any error messages. We want to parse and present this information in a customized format.
I would like to clarify if this approach can be used to capture information specifically after the terraform apply step. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: `terraform apply -json` can only capture information _during_ the apply step, because after the apply step it won't be running anymore. I imagine anything that happens after `terraform apply` has completed is outside of Terraform's scope, so I'm not sure what to suggest. It might help to edit your question to be more specific about exactly what data you want to collect, including some examples of how you'd prefer to have that data formatted so it's clear both what information you want to gather and what format you want to gather it in.

Comment: Sorry for my typing mistake, I wanted to say Terraform plan does not apply, There are two output overviews one happens when we trigger Terraform plan, and after getting the output then we trigger Terraform apply. I am specifically interested in extracting and presenting important information from the Terraform plan output, not the apply output. Terraform plan output contains a large number of lines and can be overwhelming to analyze.
This will help us quickly identify the essential information without being overwhelmed by unnecessary output.

Comment: There are two different ways to obtain data about the plan phase. You can use `terraform plan -json` to make Terraform expose the underlying events that would normally drive the UI. You can also save your plan to a file `terraform plan -out=tfplan` and then ask for a JSON representation of just the plan (without the actions that were taken to build it) with `terraform show -json tfplan`.

Comment: Isn't it possible by a python coding and then merge it with CI/CD pipeline, after trigger terraform plan, then CI/CD pipeline will execute the Python code.

Comment: Yes, you can use a Python program to analyze the output of the commands I've described which produce JSON data.